# Add event listener to all childeren

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I have a button that when clicked calls a function that creates divs and adds them as childeren to another div which acts as a container.

I tryed this at the end of the function:

```
x = document.getElementById("box_area").childNodes;
x[x.length-1].addEventListener("click",alert("test"),false) //to add a listener to the div just created.
```

when the button is click, the function is triggered on click of the button, and not when the divs are clicked.

Any idea how I can add an event listener to each dynamic div because mine arent working.

Comment: What browser are you testing this in? `addEventListener` only works in newer versions of IE. Anyways, the second parameter must be a reference to a function, not a statement. And make sure this is in some form of `window.onload`

Comment: Why not bind to the parent element, and then test `e.target`/`e.srcElement` to see if it's a descendant, rather than dynamically adding the (same?) event to each of the childNodes?

Comment: You didn't wrap `alert` in a function. You should.

Comment: Why don't you add the event listener to your created object first, and then add it to `box_area`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
x[x.length-1].addEventListener("click", function () {
    alert("test");
}, false);
```

Note that the second parameter is a reference to an anonymous function. Before, you were immediately calling `alert` when this line was executed, not accomplishing what you actually want.

Here's an example, using basically what you've provided: http://jsfiddle.net/8Q63G/

And an even better example, by sharing a function: http://jsfiddle.net/8Q63G/1/

Although to support all browsers, you should use something like:

```
window.onload = function () {
    x = document.getElementById("box_area").childNodes;
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        //x[i].addEventListener("click", boxClicker, false);
        addEvent(x[i], "click", boxClicker);
    }
};

function addEvent(element, event_name, func) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(event_name, func, false); 
    } else if (element.attachEvent)  {
        element.attachEvent("on"+event_name, func);
    }
}

function boxClicker() {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Q63G/3/

Although there are several more options. You could add one event to the "box_area" element, then check the `event`'s `target` and/or `srcElement` properties to see if it's a child you're looking for. Also, you could attach the event **before** adding the element to the DOM - this is the same thing as my solution, except it doesn't require you to access the `.childNodes` and get the last item.

Comment: Brilliant, i've been puzzling this for a fair amount of time! I'll take this onboard and do some reading! Many thanks.

Comment: @Larry No problem. You might want to look at http://ejohn.org/projects/flexible-javascript-events/ **and** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener

Answer (score -1):

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y8yBD/

```
$('#box_area').on('click', 'div', function (e) {
    alert('test');
});

$('button').click(function () {
    $('#box_area').append('<div class="box"></div>');
});
```

Comment: There was no [tag:jquery] tag therefore it's best to explain that you are using jQuery, and, importantly *why* you're using jQuery (when it wasn't reqested).

Comment: Per discussion in meta, jQuery (or any other answer that uses a library) should not be offered unless that library is mentioned in the question, already being used in the question or there's some particular reason which you explain for using this library that was not requested.  It should be very clear in this question that the OP is using plain javascript (addEventListener) and not using jQuery.  Besides, the only problem the OP had was that they didn't know how to pass a function to `addEventListener()` which certainly doesn't require jQuery.